# Returning a std::string from a function that might throw an exception

Tags: c++, string, exception

I do this a lot in Java...

```
String something = "A default value.";
try {
    something = this.aFunctionThatMightThrowAnException();
} catch (Exception ignore) { }
this.useTheString(something);
```

Now I'm trying to find an equivalent approach for `std::string`.  Here is what I have...

```
std::string something("A defualt value.");
try {
    something = this->aFunctionThatMightThrowAnException();
} catch (const std::exception& ignore) { }
this->useTheString(something);
```

For completeness, here is what `aFunctionThatMightThrowAnException()` might look like...

```
std::string MyClass::aFunctionThatMightThrowAnException() {
    /* Some code that might throw an std::exception. */
    std::string aString("Not the default.");
    return aString;
}
```

I have three questions about the C++ version:

- Is this an accepted approach to this kind of problem?  Or is it more common to pass the `something` into `aFunction` as a reference?
- Is my assignment to `something` as the return from `aFunction...` safe?  Specifically is the memory that was originally assigned to `"A default value."` released?
- Are there side effects I can't see in the case an exception is thrown?

Comment: `catch(...)` is more general; it will catch anything, which seems appropriate here.

Comment: @Pete: I dunno... the function is called `aFunctionThatMightThrowAnException`, not `aFunctionThatMightThrowAValueOfAnyTypeWhatsoever`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I don't see the point of only catching certain types of exceptions if the goal is to catch all exceptions.

Comment: @PeteBecker: `int` is not an exception, but your `...` will catch that. Exceptions are objects of base type `std::exception`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `throw 3` throws an exception. C++ isn't Java.

Comment: @PeteBecker: No, it throws the integer `3`. I am quite aware that C++ isn't Java; the first clue was in the name, in that C++ is C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Sigh. The language definition does not distinguish between throwing an exception of type `std::exception`, throwing an exception of type `int`, and throwing an exception of type `const char *`. In all cases, the code is throwing an exception and the calling code can either catch the exception or ignore it. There are no language-level consequences for exception handling based on the distinction you are arguing for.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I don't understand what you're trying to suggest. The OP's code _clearly_ states `/* Some code that might throw an std::exception. */`. **Catching `...` is a backwards step** as it gives you _zero_ benefit over catching `std::exception` in this case, and _removes_ the ability to inspect that exception object for details.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I'm suggesting exactly what I said: "`catch(...)` is more general; it will catch anything, which seems appropriate here." Your assertion that a function named `aFunctionThatMightThrowAnException` will, self-evidently, only throw exceptions of a particular type is unwarranted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this an accepted approach to this kind of problem?

Yes.

> Or is it more common to pass the something into aFunction as a reference?

No.

> Is my assignment to something as the return from aFunction... safe? Specifically is the memory that was originally assigned to "A default value." released?

Yes.

> Are there side effects I can't see in the case an exception is thrown?

No.

Comment: I really like the design of your site.